# What can I infer from this scalar product identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

Suppose I have shown for a single vector $\lvert 0 \rangle$ that

$$\langle 0 \rvert U^\dagger \phi U \lvert 0 \rangle=\langle 0 \rvert \phi \lvert 0 \rangle$$

where $\phi$ is a certain operator and $U$ a certain unitary transformation,.

Which properties of $\phi$ would allow me to infer that $U \lvert 0 \rangle=e^{i\alpha}\lvert 0 \rangle$ for some phase $\alpha$? For example, if $\phi$ is the identity then the equation holds for all $\lvert 0 \rangle$ so you cannot deduce anything, but I have the feeling that for certain $\phi$ you can.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you are assuming that the equality holds for all $\phi$.

Then, yes, I think you are right. If you don't mind, I will use slightly different notations: $x = \langle 0 |$. I then take for $\phi$ the orthogonal projector $\pi$ on the line generated by $x$: $\pi(x) = x$, $\pi_{|x^\perp} = 0$.

$$\|x\|^2 = |\langle x, \pi(x)\rangle| = |\langle U(x), \pi(U(x))\rangle| \leq \|U(x)\| \|\pi(U(x)) \| \leq \|x\|^2.
$$
So the inequality is an equality. Equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality implies that the vectors are proportional. There is some constant $C$ such that $U(x) = C\pi(U(x))$. Since $\pi(U(x))$ is proportional to $x$, $U(x)$ is proportional to $x$ and we are done.

Comment: Surely this would only be true if the $U^\dagger$ and $U$ were next to each other?

Comment: Indeed. I misread your question. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @Coudy I think it's understood that the equality holds for all operator $\phi$.

Comment: Ah, I see now what is the question. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Apologies for being unclear, I mean it holds for a specific operator $\phi$ (but not the identity) and was wondering what properties of $\phi$ would allow you to deduce $U \lvert 0 \rangle=e^{i\alpha}\lvert 0 \rangle$ or not.